# Refresh Button in Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to update the accordion header FormationName information directly from UI when user clicks on refresh button.

However, in the current design accordion header is updated by hard coded string ("party") just for testing purpose. When user clicks on refresh button first accordion header FormationName is updated.

```
$("#refresh").click(function () {
    myData.offsetFormations[0]["FormationName"] = "party";
    $('#accordion').accordion('destroy');
    build();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/85/

Comment: I swear this exact question was asked this yesterday...

Comment: @Tim Lewis, yes, I also worked on the same question, but that guy he deleted but I am still working on it to find out. If it is wrong to ask this question, I could delete it. However, I believe it might be useful for others as well. Should I delete?

Comment: Huh I see. I'm still confused what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish... It might get deleted as a duplicate, who can say. You can link to it if you'd like, add a reference to it in your question.

Comment: I want to update header formationName from accordion by itself, rather than hard coded string.

Comment: So if you change the value to something like `Test` you want `myData.offsetFormations[0]["FormationName"] = "Test";`?

Comment: yes, that is what has been done in the question, however, I would like to know how to change it directly from accordion. accordion header is editable in the current design

Comment: Yeah I get that, you want the value changed dynamically, and not hardcoded. Can you change all of the headers or just the top one?

Comment: Once you click on accordion header, you could type what you want.

Comment: Ok. Working on a solution then. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's what I came up with. First, add all elements with the class `.formationName` into an array. It should have the same length as your `myData.offsetFormations`:

```
var names = [];
var counter = 0;
$(".formationName").each(function(){
   names[counter] = $(this).text();
   counter++;
});
```

Logging this element will result in an array of 8 names, which have the values of the headers (adjusted or otherwise.)

Next, loop over your `myData.offsetFormations` and set the value of `[i]["FormationName"]` to that of the name array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myData.offsetFormations.length; i++){
  myData.offsetFormations[i]["FormationName"] = names[i];
}
```

Your whole function should look like this:

```
$("#refresh").click(function () {
    var names = [];
    var counter = 0;
    $(".formationName").each(function(){
       names[counter] = $(this).text();
        counter++;
    }); 
    for(var i = 0; i < myData.offsetFormations.length; i++){
         myData.offsetFormations[i]["FormationName"] = names[i];
    }

    $('#accordion').accordion('destroy');
    build();
});
```

And here's the updated fiddle showing the function in action:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/88/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeap, it works very well. let me learn from your solution. Thanks a lot for the further clarifications. Thanks Lewis, cheers.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help you figure that out. Cheers.